# CiviCRM send notification to admin if payment goes failed on recurring charges

Tags: payment-processor, recurring-contributions, iatspayments

I am using IATS payment processor. I want to get notified if any recurring charge goes failed.

Comment: we have done some initial work on notifications when a normal payment fails (is incomplete). I assume something similar could be done for recurring if something doesn't already exist

Comment: We are trying this with the data processor extension, comparing the old recurring contribution status to the news one (we only only look at those where payment couldn't be taken at all after x number of attempts) and have a dashlet as the output. Probably just as easy to trigger an email at the same time. CiviRules may also work on the activity for 'Recurring contribution cancelled'

Comment: How about creating rule when payment is set to failed send email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to CiviCRM Stack Exchange!

Navigate to Administer -> CiviContribute -> iATS Payments settings -> Here you can enter an email address which should be notified of failures (first option). There are some other settings here you may want to explore as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As others said in the comments, CiviRules can work in this scenario; if you set it up where the trigger is "contribution changed," and the conditions are that the contribution is failed and the contribution recur ID is not null (just to eliminate the possibility of getting flagged for a failed one-time payment), you can then send an email to yourself and/or the contributor notifying you/them about the failed payment.

Answer (score 0):

Believe this feature has been included in the 1.7.5 version ( https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm/milestone/1?closed=1  ) which is in beta stage ( January 2023 )

[image]